# How can pathForAuxiliaryExecutable sometimes be nil?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My program executes a small c Unix subprogram using NSTask. It does so by getting a path with

`NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForAuxiliaryExecutable:@"appName"];`

and then handing that path to

`[task setLaunchPath: path];`

Works great almost all the time. But I've been getting occasional crash reports, where 'path` is nil. Not that the subprogram crashes, that the OS can't find it?

How could this happen? I thought it was cosmic rays the first time, but it's happened about four times now. All on this one executable (so far).

FYI, the program is code-signed but distributed outside Mac Store. This is built with Xcode 7; the relevant build phase is `Copy Executables`, where I copy and code-sign five such executables. When I look at the built program, the five programs are sitting in MacOS; there are not any duplicates anywhere else in the program. The failing one is 176K in size.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForAuxiliaryExecutable:):

> This method returns the appropriate path for modern application and
>   framework bundles. This method may not return a path for non-standard
>   bundle formats or for some older bundle formats.

So, it may return `nil`. I would advise to safeguard yourself from crashes by `nil` check before using it:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForAuxiliaryExecutable:@"appName"];

if (path == nil) {
   NSLog("Executable does not exists");
} else {
   [task setLaunchPath: path];
}
```

Comment: I do have such a check now, so it no longer crashes, but I need to figure out why pathForAuxiliaryExecutable fails sporadically

Comment: Hmmm, that would be a matter of investing time and debug locally. Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate it, but with thousands of folks running the program (many daily) and only a couple ever hitting this problem, it's going be interesting to isolate!

Comment: Yeah - I agree. But at least this `nil` check would avoid it crashing and so no bad user experience. Have someone in your team to spend healthy time debugging it locally. Try & replicate is the ray of hope :)!